# Format date/time using local time zone

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart, datetime-format

In Flutter I need to parse and format date/time based on what my REST API passes back. The date/time format the server sends back is `2020-01-28T13:52:30.878+0000`. In this example based on my locale it should be formatted as 8:52:30 AM EST. Does anyone know how I can achieve this using either a standard Dart package or some third-party package?

Answer (score 2):

Just figured it out, using DateTime class there is a method `toLocal()` that does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime.parse("2020-01-28T13:52:30.878+0000") to parse this format.

if GMT+5

```
formatedTime = DateTime.parse("2020-01-28T13:52:30.878+0000");
farmattedTime.add(Duration(hours: 5));
```

Comment: That is what I am currently using in my code but it does not honor local time zone.  It formats it as 13:52.30.

Comment: I have updated the answer, please check if it helps.

Comment: I answered my own question, see what I wrote.  Works perfectly.

Comment: The `add` function returns a new `DateTime` object, it does not modify the original.